# Get one document from Firestore and return it to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have less experience with NodeJS, but I am trying to obtain one User document from Firestore.

```
const fs = firebase.firestore();
const usersRef = fs.collection('users');


let findUserByContact = (contact) => {
    let res = usersRef.where('contact', '==', contact).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            return querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

I am trying to return the first document thats found. However that will always returns undefined when I am calling `findUserByContact`.

I could use `console.log` to see the output of my query. But I can't manage to assign it to a variable.

I've read into Promises, and I saw that it has to resolve something. I was trying to call `resolve` with the data I wanted to return but that gave me an error as wel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining), as follows:

```
let findUserByContact = (contact) => {
    return usersRef.where('contact', '==', contact).get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            return querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

---

Note that the answer of @AkashDathan is also totally valid and the use of async/await makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use the async/await syntax

```
let findUserByContact = async (contact) => {
    let querySnapshot = await usersRef.where('contact', '==', contact).get();
    if (querySnapshot.empty) return false;

    return querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
};
```